# Do I need an MFi license just to test?

Tags: ios, hardware, mfi

I've worked with iOS, but never with any external hardware to connect to the device.

I'm wondering if I need to purchase an MFi license to begin working with hardware and iOS. However after going through some of [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502) I'm not sure if I do for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy to a device you will need a paid apple account. Without you are restricted to just using the simulators.

Comment: The OP is asking about hardware development, not just normal apps.

Comment: I know that, but if i want to connect hardware to the device i deploy on will I need an MFi license?

Comment: Well, might be better to put "developing for hardware running iOS" instead of "working with hardware and iOS" in the question. Sorry - I don't know. Maybe someone else can help.